# How do I use a dictionary or a list from python in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

In Python views I have a dictionary which looks like this, for example:

```
{ "r8s8": 0, "r8s7": 0, "r7s7": 1, "r7s8": 1 }
```

I would like to use it in my template and go through every element.

```
$.each(my_dict_data_in_template, function(index, value) {
```

I tried using JSON (`json.dumps()`), but either I haven't converted it properly or it just doesn't work. Also, can I somehow get both keys and the values from the dictionary in templates?

Comment: How have you output the JSON to the JS from your Python code?

Comment: using return HttpResponse(my_dictionary)

Comment: So it's coming from an AJAX request?

Comment: yes. I tried printing out that data as an alert in template and in goes through but as all the keys sticker together and no values.

Comment: Assuming this is Django, how about: `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(my_dictionary), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: Thanks. Now the data in my template looks like e.g. {"r8s5": 0, "r8s6": 1, "r8s4": 1, "r7s4": 1, "r7s5": 0, "r7s6": 1}, but it still is a string and I don't know how to access keys nor values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: @Booboo do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Try getting the data with `$.getJSON()`. See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. Or if you have successfully fetched the string then convert it to an object with `my_dict = JSON.parse(s);` where s is the string.

Comment: I should add: Then call `$.each` against `my_dict`. But I assume you got that.